# Hard transition of other properties when display property is involved

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I want to fade between two differently sized elements within a container overlaying each other. The first element should be faded out, then the container resized and finally the other element faded in.

Here's the related snippet:

```js
var layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
var layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");

function switchLayers() {
  layer1.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    layer2.classList.add("fadein");
  });
  layer1.classList.add("fadeout");
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

#layer1 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

#layer2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

#layer1.fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

#layer2.fadein {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="switchLayers()">Switch layers</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="layer1" class="layer"></div>
  <div id="layer2" class="layer"></div>
</div>
```

When the second layer's `display` property is set to `block` it works as expected, i.e. the opacity is changed from 0 to 1 within a second. Though if it's set to `none`, the transition suddenly is discrete.

I've tried to set `all` within the `transition` value to transition all properties and also tried to include the `display` property in the transition like this:

```css
transition: display 0s, opacity 1s ease-out;
```

Though without success. Note that because the container should resize to the size of the currently displayed layer, the `visibility` property can't be used (as it hides the element but still lets it occupy the space).

How to made this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: The difference to that article is that I want to avoid `visibility` to be able to resize the container. I've edited my question to outline the difference.

Comment: The duplicate explains why you _can not_ transition the display property; so you _have to_ chose a different method of making the element show/no show.

Comment: I don't want to transition the `display` property (it's clear to me that its transition happens discretely from not displayed to displayed). Though setting it obviously breaks the transitions of all *other* properties, which seems to be an implementation bug, because I can't see anything in the [CSS Transitions specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/) explaining that behavior.

Comment: display:none means an element behaves as if it was not there at all; specifically it frees the browser from having to calculate _any_ of the other property’s actual values ("computed value"). And since those aren’t calculated, you do not have proper _starting_ values to transition those to anything either.

Comment: Sounds logical for `display:none;`, though as it's set to `display:block;` on the rule applied when switching layers, the starting values of the previous rule should be taken into account again. And I still don't see anything in the spec. saying that the values of the other properties are disregarded on `display:none;`, so I'm [asking for clarification on the CSSWG issue tracker](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1064).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `visibility` property instead of `display`.

For more information regarding the state changes in `visibility` and `display`, refer [article](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337).

For transitioning the parent `height`, you have to manually change the `height` property of the `#container`. Using `display: block` & `display: none` will never transition the parent.

Refer code:

```js
var layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
var layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");

function switchLayers() {
  layer1.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    layer2.classList.add("fadein");
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = "170px";
  });
  layer1.classList.add("fadeout");
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.layer {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

#layer1 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

#layer2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  visibility: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

#layer1.fadeout {
  visibility: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#layer2.fadein {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="switchLayers()">Switch layers</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="layer1" class="layer"></div>
  <div id="layer2" class="layer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though this makes the container take the size of the highest layer causing a probably huge space after short layers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way. Transitions do not work on `display`, nor do they work on auto `height`. So, `visibility` is a good bet.

> Note that because the container should resize to the size of the
>   currently displayed layer, the visibility property can't be used (as
>   it hides the element but still lets it occupy the space).

Then, you will need to hack it out. You can make use of `min-height`. Give a *faux* `min-height` to your `container`, and then apply the `height` of your `layer2` to it once the transition ends. Also, because `display` on `layer2` will block the transition, you need to separate out the classes for `display` and `opacity` and space out their application using a zero timeout in between.

Here is a crude idea:

```js
var layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1"),
    layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2"),
    container = document.getElementById("container"),
    h = window.getComputedStyle(layer2).getPropertyValue("height");

container.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'layer1') {
    // apply layer2 height to container min-height
    container.style.minHeight = h; 
  }
  if (e.target.id === 'container') { 
    // First show the layer2
    layer2.classList.add("show"); 
    // Then a dummy pause to fadein
    setTimeout(function(){
      layer2.classList.add("fadein");
    }, 0);
  }
}, false);

function switchLayers() {
  layer1.classList.add("fadeout");
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px; overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 1px; /* faux min-height */
  transition: min-height 1s linear;
}

.layer { position: relative; width: 400px; }

#layer1 {
  height: 100px; float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

#layer2 {
  height: 150px; background-color: red;
  display: none; opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

#layer1.fadeout { opacity: 0; }
#layer2.show { display: block; } /* Separate out display */
#layer2.fadein { opacity: 1; } /* Separate out opacity */
```

```html
<button onclick="switchLayers()">Switch layers</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="layer1" class="layer"></div>
  <div id="layer2" class="layer"></div>
</div>
```